# Question about the support of a module $M$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A \not= \{0 \}$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ be an $A$-module. Define $$\text{Supp} (M) = \{ P \in \operatorname{Spec} A : M_P \not= 0 \}$$

My first question is if $0$ is the element $0/1$?

Also can I have a example of a ring $A$ and a module $M$ such that $M_p=0$ for some prime ideal and where $M_p \not= 0$ for some prime ideal? I am having troubles to get a picture in my head of $\text{Supp}(M)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0$ means the trivial module (whose underlying additive group is the trivial group).

As an example pick $A = \Bbb Z$, $M = \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$; then $M_{(2)} = M$ but $M_{\mathfrak p}$ is trivial for all other primes $\mathfrak p$.

To see this last statement, recall the definition of $S^{-1}M$; it's equivalence classes of fractions $a/b$ ($a \in M, b \in S$), where $a/b$ is equivalent to $c/d$ if there's an $s \in S$ with $s(ad-bc)=0$. We want to show that $a/b=0/1$ for all $a,b$. Now $2 \in \Bbb Z \setminus (p)$ for all $p \neq 2$; and $2(a)=0\in M$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the example, but my first question remains unanswered. $M_p$ consist of fractions, if $M_p=0$ what fraction is $0$? Is it the fraction $0/1$?

Comment: I am confused, $0$ is the additive identity of of $M_p$ right? This one is unique, so what is it? $M_p$ consist of fractions, what fraction is $0$? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Elements of $M_p$ are *equivalence classes* of fractions. That $M_p = 0$ means that it's the zero module, i.e. there's only one equivalence class. So any fraction you write down will be *equivalent* to $0/1$ (which is the additive identity of $M_p$ whether $M_p$ is trivial or not).

Comment: Can I ask something about your example, as I understand $M_{(3)}= S^{-1}M=(\mathbb{Z} \setminus (3))^{-1}M$ and $M$ consist of just 2 elements. If we pick $5 \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus (3)$ and $1+ 2\mathbb{Z} \in Z/ 2\mathbb{Z}$ then how does the element $(1/5)*(1+ 2\mathbb{Z})$ look like? As I understand we have $(1/5)*(1+ 2\mathbb{Z}) = (1 + 2 \mathbb{Z})$ so that $M_{(3)}$ is not trivial. I really think I am missing something here, maybe how the elements of $S^{-1}M$ look like, is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks.